# How can I get the executable file folder without the .exe name?

Tags: c#, path, exe

How can I make a string variable containing path to my win-app executable folder? I know that there's the simple command `Application.ExecutablePath` which returns all the path including the .exe name, but I need that path without the .exe name.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: I'm using c# language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@shf301's answer works for Windows Forms apps. The generic way that should work for any executable (*.exe), whether it's a Windows Forms or not is

```
string fqn = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location ;
string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(fqn) ;
```

Or even easier:

```
string baseDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory ;
```

`AppDomain.BaseDirectory` returns "the base directory that the assembly resolver uses to probe for assemblies." For ordinary executables, that's the directory containing the entrypoint assembly.

Answer (score 3):

You want [System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string appPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```